# nodejs REPL doesn't process JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying node with REPL, parsing from string failed like this:

```
$node
> var str="{'a':1,'b':2}"
undefined
> var js=JSON.parse(str)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
```

But the reversed parse seems OK:

```
> var json = {a : ' 1 ',b : ' 2'};
undefined
> var str = JSON.stringify(json);
undefined
> str
'{"a":" 1 ","b":" 2"}'
```

Where did I get wrong?

Comment: JSON has double quotes for property names and strings ...single ones are invalid. Paste that in jsonlint.com will see it is invalid as the error is telling you. Conversely a javascript object can have singles, doubles or none for property names  so long as there are no special characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax error in your JSON:

```
{'a':1,'b':2}
 ^
 |
 '--- invalid syntax. Illegal character (')
```

JSON is not the same thing as Javascript object literals. JSON is a file/data format which is compatible with object literal syntax but is more strict. The JSON format was specified by Douglas Crockford and documented at http://json.org/

Some of the differences between JSON and object literals:

- Property names are strings
- Strings start and end with double quotes (")
- Hexadecimals numbers (eg. 0x1234) are not supported

etc.